# How to automatically adjust the elements of QGridLayout to fit in a row when the screen window size is changed in QT Designer and Pyside6?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-creator, qt-designer, pyqt6

I have created a scroll area and set the layout to a grid in qt designer. Then I added some frames(city profile) with fixed sizes inside the scroll area(QGridLayout). I'm trying to dynamically add or delete the city profile frames. When I add "city profile" to the grid layout, it should adapt the position automatically according to the screen size. Like, when the window is not maximized, in one row, it should show only four or five "city profile" frames but when the window is maximized, there is more space in the row and it should occupy more "city profile" frames in a single row. I tried setting the layout size constraint but it's not giving the output I want. Also, I have googled about it but couldn't find any results.

**Demo Image when the window is in normal view**
[image]

**Demo Image when the window is maximized**
[image]

**Markings**

[image]

Comment: I suspect you're looking for something like a [flow layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html).

Comment: @G.M. yes, like flow layout. but i cannot find flow layout in QT designer

Comment: A flow layout is not provided by Qt out of the box. The link of G.M. is an example of how to extend the `QLayout` class to implement a flow layout. So you can use it as a starting point for your flow layout implementation.

Comment: ok . also, can i add "city profile" frames dynamically if i created it in QT Designer in to the flow layout?

Comment: Considering what you're showing, another possibility could be to use a QListView with an appropriate model, and set its iconMode, which allows to get exactly this kind of layout.

Comment: @musicamante I can only use texts or images inside the ListView right?

Comment: @Sahal since it's an item view, you can show anything: for simple cases, you can use index widgets, if you're not showing too many items you can even consider QListWidget (in that case they're called [item widgets](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget), but it's exactly the same thing); if you need a more advanced content, then it's better to use a custom item delegate, and in that case you can literally show anything you want, since you can customize the whole implementation, including custom drawing of the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the images you provided, a possible alternative would be to use a QListView with a related model or even a QListWidget (which inherits from QListView), and then set it up to show items from left to right and ensure that wrapping is enabled. This is how Qt shows files in a non-native QFileDialog.

Then, for simple cases, you can use [`setIndexWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) (or [`setItemWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#setItemWidget) for QListWidget, which does the same).

This is a possible implementation:

```py
class CityFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, city):
        super().__init__()
        self.imageLabel = QLabel(pixmap=QPixmap('city.png'))
        self.cityLabel = QLabel(city, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.button = QToolButton(icon=QIcon.fromTheme('document-save'))

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(1)
        layout.addWidget(self.imageLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.cityLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 1, 2, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)

        self.setFixedSize(layout.sizeHint())

class FlowContainer(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # make it look like a normal scroll area
        self.viewport().setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Window)
        # display items from left to right, instead of top to bottom
        self.setFlow(self.LeftToRight)
        # wrap items that don't fit the width of the viewport
        # similar to self.setViewMode(self.IconMode)
        self.setWrapping(True)
        # prevent user repositioning
        self.setMovement(self.Static)
        # always re-layout items when the view is resized
        self.setResizeMode(self.Adjust)

        self.setHorizontalScrollMode(self.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.setVerticalScrollMode(self.ScrollPerPixel)
        self.setSpacing(4)

    def addCity(self, city):
        item = QListWidgetItem(city)
        item.setFlags(item.flags() & ~(Qt.ItemIsSelectable|Qt.ItemIsEnabled))
        self.addItem(item)
        frame = CityFrame(city)
        item.setSizeHint(frame.sizeHint())
        self.setItemWidget(item, frame)


class Test(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(640, 320)
        self.cityList = FlowContainer()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.cityList)

        Cities = ['New York', 'London', 'Budapest', 'Novi Grad', 'Malibu', 'Kathmandu']
        for city in Cities:
            self.cityList.addCity(city)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Test()
    test.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

<sup>The code above is for PyQt5, for PyQt6 you'll need to adapt the namespaces of enums, like `QPalette.ColorRole.Window`, etc.</sup>

And this is the result of the code above:

[image: screenshot at startup]

And after resizing:

[image: screenshot with different layout]

Note that if you plan on displaying lots of items (in the order of hundreds or thousands), then you should consider using a custom delegate instead of index widgets, which allows advanced and custom painting and is much lighter for bigger models.